# Why does Swift 1.2 require forced-unwrapping?

Tags: swift, option-type

In Swift 1.2, the following

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentififer("mycell"), forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

now must use !

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentififer("mycell"), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

In the first example, *cell* can be nil?  Seems strange for a constant to be nil.

In the second example, Swift is making sure there is a value at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not "forced unwrapping". It has nothing to do with optionals or unwrapping. It's a new version of the cast operator, `as`. In Swift 1.2, we use instead the `as!` operator when failably downcasting; the exclamation mark is intended to serve as a reminder that if this thing turns out not to be the class we are claiming, we will crash. This was *always* true; the use of `as!` instead of `as` is just a way of helping to keep you conscious of the fact.

Comment: Wouldn't it have crashed anyway without the bang syntax?

Comment: Yes, I said that. Read what I said, please.

Comment: So as vs as! is the same thing?

Comment: No, because some casts are not failable downcasts. Previously we did not distinguish. Now we do. In Swift 1.2, `as` is used only for upcasts and bridged casts, because they cannot fail. `as!` is used for downcasts, because they can.

Answer (score 0):

because the downcasting must be success.. using the forced way doesnot return nil.. So quiet great way to make the casting happen successful ..if it doesnot there is a run time error...